# Why doesn't the rethrown exception work as expected?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance

My sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent{ 
        public: 
            virtual void who()
            {
                cout<<"I am parent"<<endl;
            }
};
class Child: public Parent 
{
    public: 
        void who()
        {
            cout<<"I am child"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    try{
        try{
            Child C;
            Parent &P=C;
            throw P;
        }
        catch(Parent &P)
        {
            P.who();
            throw;//here it just propagates the Child exception
        }
    }
    catch(Parent &P)
    {
            P.who();//parent who is getting executed
    }

}
```

I was going through Scott Meyers More Effective C++, Item 12. So when I rethrow it should propagate the Child exception. But the  outer `catch` `P.who()` gives the parent `who()`.
And when I change the outer catch to `Child` type(not mentioned in the program) it terminates the process. Where is my understanding wrong?

What Scott Meyers says(with my edits)

```
class Widget{...};
class Special Widget: public Widget { ... };
void passAndThrowWidget()
{
   SpecialWidget localSpecialWidget;
   ...
   Widget& rw = localSpecialWidget;
   throw rw; //this throws an exception of type Widget!
} 

................
................

catch(Widget &w)   //catch Widget exceptions
{
  ...
  throw;     //rethrow the exception so it continues to propagate.
}
.............
.............
```

If the exception originally thrown was of type `Special Widget`, the `catch` block would propagate a `Special Widget` exception , even though `w`'s static type is Widget. This is because no copy is make when the exception is rethrown.

Comment: For me, the inner catch already prints `I am parent` (with VC, clang and GCC). So the exception was never of type `Child`, before or after `throw;` Re-throw is a red herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> throw rw; //this throws an exception of type Widget!
> ```

This does not throw a `SpecialWidget`. It only throws a `Widget`.

`throw;` never changes the type of the thrown object. If the original object was a `Child`, it will still be a child after `throw;`.

Comment: so object slicing has happend here?

Comment: "**[except.throw]/3** Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object, called the *exception object*. The temporary is ... used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler (15.3)." So, `throw rw;` doesn't throw an object referred to by `rw`, but a temporary object copy-initialized from `rw`. Yes, slicing happens here.